# Contact form 7 - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a contact form using the 'Contact form 7' plugin. There is a facility to add placeholder text to all fields however you can't add this placeholder to a dropdown menu.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Maybe target the list with Javascript but add the disabled attribute to that value?

Thank you!
Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use first_as_label option of contact form 7 to make some text as placeholder, so that first option will convert as disabled option with placeholder text.

```
[select* Test first_as_label "Placeholder goes here" "Option 1" "Option 2"]
```

https://contactform7.com/checkboxes-radio-buttons-and-menus/

Comment: Okay I see! Where abouts would I render this script? (What file)? Thank you!

Comment: its not in a file, you need to insert it in that particular form in contact form in wp-admin

Comment: Wow, Charan that worked perfectly!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is no ways to add placeholders in dropdowns in CF7.

Maybe [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213805/how-to-add-placeholder-for-contact-form7-for-dropdown) can help.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would be helpful

```
<select>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Option</option>
    <option value="option1">option1</option>
    <option value="option2">option2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: How does this help OP? How can OP implement this in Contact Form 7?